# Need Help to read text file

Tags: java, xml, file-io

i am a new in JAVA and i want to read text file and write it in XML here is my input:

1. R.-J. Roe, J. Appl.Phys. 36, 2024 (1965).

and the output but is:

```
        <ref id="1">
        <label>1</label>
        <citation-alternatives>
            <mixed-citation>R.-J. Roe, J. Appl.Phys. 36, 2024 (1965).</mixed-citation>
        </citation-alternatives>
    </ref>
```

put in many cases this input comes in two lines without space between them like this:

1. R.-J. Roe,

   J. Appl.Phys. 36, 2024 (1965).

and the output will be this:

```
        <ref id="1">
        <label>1</label>
        <citation-alternatives>
            <mixed-citation>R.-J. Roe, </mixed-citation>
        </citation-alternatives>
    </ref>

    <ref id="1">
        <label>1</label>
        <citation-alternatives>
            <mixed-citation>J. Appl.Phys. 36, 2024 (1965).</mixed-citation>
        </citation-alternatives>
    </ref>
```

Now my question is how can i read this two lines as one stirng to be like the first output?
and here is my code:

```
try {
            String strLine;
            String num="";
            String mix="";
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            // Back element
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Back");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            // ref-list element
            Element reflist = doc.createElement("ref-list");
            rootElement.appendChild(reflist);

            while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)                   
                
            {                       
                if (strLine.equals("")) {
                    continue;
                }
                int dotIndex = strLine.indexOf(".");

                num = strLine.substring(0,dotIndex);
                mix = strLine.substring(dotIndex+2,strLine.length());



                // ref element
                Element ref= doc.createElement("ref");
                reflist.appendChild(ref);

                // set attribute of ref element
                Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
                attr.setValue(num);
                ref.setAttributeNode(attr);

                // label element
                Element label = doc.createElement("label");
                ref.appendChild(label);
                label.setTextContent(num);

                // citation-alternatives element
                Element citationalternatives = doc.createElement("citation-alternatives");
                ref.appendChild(citationalternatives);

                // mixed-citation element
                Element mixedcitation = doc.createElement("mixed-citation");
                citationalternatives.appendChild(mixedcitation);
                mixedcitation.setTextContent(mix);
            }
```

Comment: Parse your file until you find the end of your input - look for `).\n` or whatever - and then create your `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is creating two `<ref>` records when it reads in a record containing an extra line break is that you are using line breaks to define when records begin.

You need to clearly define what marks the **start of a record.**

For instance, maybe all records begin with a number followed by a period. Maybe it's even more predictable: they all begin with sequential numbers followed by a period. Making use of this logic, we can move your creation of a new element conditional:

```
    Element ref= doc.createElement("ref");
    while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {                       
        if (strLine.equals(""))
            continue;
        int dotIndex = strLine.indexOf(".");
        num = strLine.substring(0,dotIndex);
        mix = strLine.substring(dotIndex+2,strLine.length());
        if(refStart(strLine)) {
            ref= doc.createElement("ref");
            reflist.appendChild(ref);
        }
        //now decide how to parse the input - maybe it will be different depending on 
        //whether the line we just read starts a new record or continues one from
        //the previous line.
    }


    public boolean refStart(String line) {
        if(line.length()<2) 
            return false;
        int dotIndex = strLine.indexOf(".");
        if(dotIndex<=0 || dotIndex>5) //assuming largest value is 99999
            return false;
        String numString = strLine.substring(0,dotIndex);
        for(int i=0; i<numString.length(); i++) {
            if(!Character.isDigit(numString.charAt(i) )
               return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work @Thorn and i can't catch the Error :(, but many thanks for your effort.

Comment: when i choose the second input to run it, gives me exception 
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at Main.actionPerformed(Main.java:113)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

Before inserting strLine into the element, check if strLine.endsWith( "," ), if so, read the next line (and so on) and append to the first strLine.